# How can I reset password and email it using a CSV?

Tags: email, powershell, password, csv, reset

In a nutshell, I have a CSV file with First name, Last name, and personal Email. I would like to use this file to rest the users passwords and then send them an email with their login information.

I had to populate a bunch of users before "going live". I pulled all users that have not logged in and combined them with their personal emails. Their UPN is first.last so adding that to the file is easy to do if needed.

I have found some solutions that skirt around what I need, like how to do it during initial population, or on a singular basis. Feels like there is a connection to be made, but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Why would you ever email credentials, do you know how insecure email is? Especially personal email? Yikes

Comment: You never store user passwords envclair.

Comment: @Jacob Because that is our option at the moment. We're a non-profit youth development that is dispersed all over the state. To meet each one to provide it is not feasible, no do we have a way to send it via snail mail short of copy and pasting to word, also not a great solution cost wise. There is no sensitive information on the system at this point and the admins are not going to be affected.